# The Comment/ Note-wise function for rare leverage

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, comments

I found a specific application like a comment/ note function as below picture  [in Microsoft official template](https://templates.office.com/en-us/retirement-financial-planner-tm04022385).

[image]

It would show as long as the cursor is in a specific cell, but I couldn't figure out how to modify or create it. The thing I only can do is drag the item and move it.

For my understanding, I reckon the function is not the same as neither traditional comment-function nor note-function.

If you face the problem and could give any keywords or hint for this item?

Many thank for any feedback in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They used Data Validation to display an Input Message when the cell is selected.

To edit it, click the "Data Validation" button on the Data ribbon.

[image]

[image: Sreenshot]

Comment: It works! Really appreciate the interpretation.